# Optimization problem - wage determination

Tags: mathematical-economics, optimization

Could someone please show how the author derives the the first order condition (14) of this optimization problem using the expressions shown here ?

For context this is taken from a labour market model where the private sector wage, w_p , is the result of Nash bargaining over the respective surpluses of the households V^h and firms V^f

[image]

Comment: Why are people so reluctant to name "the author" or "the paper"? Providing a direct link could also be useful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking the derivative of the goal function w.r.t. $w_t^P$ you get
$$
(1- \vartheta)\frac{1}{V^h_{nPt}}\frac{\partial V^h_{nPt}}{\partial w_t^P} +
\vartheta\frac{1}{V^f_{nPt}}\frac{\partial V^f_{nPt}}{\partial w_t^P} = 0
$$
which, after substituting the definitions is
$$
(1- \vartheta)\frac{1}{V^h_{nPt}}\left(\lambda_{ct}(1-\tau_n^t)\right) +
\vartheta\frac{1}{V^f_{nPt}}(-1) = 0.
$$
Rearranging
$$
(1- \vartheta)\frac{1}{V^h_{nPt}}\lambda_{ct}(1-\tau_n^t)
= \vartheta\frac{1}{V^f_{nPt}},
$$
rearranging
$$
(1- \vartheta)\lambda_{ct}(1-\tau_n^t) V^f_{nPt}
= \vartheta V^h_{nPt},
$$
QED.